# Animate on insertion/removal supplementary views

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

currently I'm studying custom UICollectionViewLayout by this lesson: https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/collectionview-animations. Everything is fine with static data, but when I'm trying to delete an item, error **'NSRangeException'** occurs in method

> layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:

I suppose it is related to getting attributes for a removed item, but it is called after I remove this item. I attempted to fix it by adding additional variable 'removedItem' and it worked, but I'm not sure if it is a common practice as it sounds like a workaround and would like to hear advice on this.

The main question is how to animate supplementary view on insert or removal of an collection view item. I have created layout as follows in attachment:[image: my layout]

where cells are bordered items with cube in center and supplementary views are colored views that are placed below every cell. For animation of items and cells I use these methods:

```
-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath {
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attr = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];

attr.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.2, 0.2), M_PI);
attr.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.collectionView.bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(self.collectionView.bounds));

return attr;
}
-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)elementIndexPath {...}
-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath {...}
-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)elementIndexPath {...}
```

For example to insert an item I use standard method:

```
[self.sampleCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
```

Which leads to proper item animation, but supplementary view just appears without animation. When I call

```
deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:
```

supplementary view not only doesn't have animation of removal, but also remains visible and is removed after I start scrolling or call 
    invalidateLayout 
on my custom layout. So, is there any way to animate supplementary views? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To remove supplementary views use

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)elementIndexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingSupplementaryElementOfKind:elementKind atIndexPath:elementIndexPath];
    attributes.alpha = 0;
    return attributes;
}
```

One way of animated disappear I've found - animation block in

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

it must be tied to view with some KVO (looks like hack)

**-----**

Another approach might be to override `prepareLayout` where you will build attributes for all supplementary views, you need. When you don't need some supplementary view anymore, do not simply remove it's attributes from your `layouInfoDictionary`  and `layoutAttributesArray` which you use in

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
and 
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Create proper attributes for hidden items instead. And in next iteration of `prepareLayout` these attributes will be removed.